# Watermark over li elements in a vertical menu

Tags: css, watermark

I want to have a background OVER li elements, but applying an image with an absolute potion on the `ul` won't let me click on the elements.
Is there a better solution than cutting a piece of the image on each of the li elements?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with your current code?

Comment: a background "over"? how is that?

Comment: and `li` elements aren't clickable anyway, so no problem there.

Comment: I'm assuming the OP has `<a>` tags inside his `<li>`s, or has an `onclick` handler for them in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Modified  my answer with Mr Lister modification: http://jsfiddle.net/R222B/
Aplied on first element in tha list. Please verify.

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><span> List1 </span><a href="#"><img src="http://www.aireuropa.com/waeam/en/estaticos/images/sky.png" /></a></li>
    <li><span> List2 </span><img src="http://www.aireuropa.com/waeam/en/estaticos/images/sky.png" /></li>
    <li><span> List3 </span><img src="http://www.aireuropa.com/waeam/en/estaticos/images/sky.png" /></li>
    <li><span> List4 </span><img src="http://www.ottopizza.co.uk/images/image.php?image=26.png&width=35" /></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    li
{
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding; 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
span
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
img
{   
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -33px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    z-index: 2;
}
a
{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: But check out this [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/t4vxB/1/) - you can't click the elements behind the images.

Comment: Yes. It's true, thanks. Maybe you can provide him a javascript solution. Maybe that would work.

Comment: Why can't you just put the `img` in the `a`? Then put the `a` on top (in the z-index), the text underneath, and the image will be clickable.